# Proper way to manually instantiate Nest.js providers

Tags: nestjs

I think I might be misunderstanding Nest.js's IoC container, or maybe DI as a whole.

I have a class, `JSONDatabase`, that I want to instantiate myself based on some config value (can either be JSON or SQL).

My `DatabaseService` provider:

```js
  constructor(common: CommonService, logger: LoggerService) {

    // eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
    const databaseType: DatabaseType = common.serverConfig.dbType as DatabaseType;

    if (databaseType === DatabaseType.JSON) {
      this.loadDatabase<JSONDatabase>(new JSONDatabase());
    } else if (databaseType === DatabaseType.SQL) {
      this.loadDatabase<SQLDatabase>(new SQLDatabase());
    } else {
      logger.error('Unknown database type.');
    }
  }
```

My `JSONDatabase` class:

```js
export class JSONDatabase implements IDatabase {
  dbType = DatabaseType.JSON;
  constructor(logger: LoggerService, io: IOService) {
    logger.log(`Doing something...`)
  }
}
```

However, the problem with this is that if I want my `JSONDatabase` to take advantage of injection, ie. it requires both `IOService` and `LoggerService`, I need to add the parameters from the `DatabaseService` constructor rather than inject them through Nest's IoC containers.

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 [ts(2554)]
json.database.ts(7, 15): An argument for 'logger' was not provided.
```

Is this the proper way to do this? I feel like manually passing these references through is incorrect, and I should use Nest's custom providers, however, I don't really understand the Nest docs on this subject. I essentially want to be able to `new JSONDatabase()` without having to pass in references into the constructor and have the Nest.js IoC container inject the existing singletons already (runtime dependency injection?).

I might be completely off base with my thinking here, but I haven't used Nest all that much, so I'm mostly working off of instinct. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have right now is because you are instantiating JSONDatabase manually when you call `new JSONDatabase()` not leveraging the DI provided by NestJS. Since the constructor expects 2 arguments (LoggerService, and IOService) and you are providing none, it fails with the message

`Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 [ts(2554)]`

I think depending on your use case you can try a couple of different options

1. If you fetch your configuration on startup and set the database once in the application lifetime you can use use a Custom provider with the `useFactory` syntax.

```js
const providers = [
  {
    provide: DatabaseService,
    useFactory: (logger: LoggerService, io: IOService, config: YourConfigService): IDatabase => {
      if (config.databaseType === DatabaseType.JSON) {
          return new JSONDatabase(logger, io);
      } else if (databaseType === DatabaseType.SQL) {
          return new SQLDatabase(logger, io);
      } else {
        logger.error('Unknown database type.');
      }
    },
    inject: [LoggerService, IOService, YourConfigService]
  },
];

@Module({
  providers,
  exports: providers
})
export class YourModule {}
```

If you have `LoggerService`, `IOService` and `YourConfigurationService` annotated with `@Injectable()` NestJS will inject them in the useFactory context. There you can check the databaseType and manually instantiate the correct `IDatabase` implementation. The drawback with this approach is that you can't easily change the database in runtime. (This might work just fine for your use case)

2. You can use strategy/factory pattern to get the correct implementation based on a type. Let say you have a method that saves to different databases based on an specific parameter.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private readonly databaseFactory: DatabaseFactory){}

  method(objectToSave: Object, type: DatabaseType) {
    databaseFactory.getService(type).save(objectToSave);
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class DatabaseFactory {

  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  getService(type: DatabaseType): IDatabase {
    this.moduleRef.get(`${type}Database`);
  }
}
```

The idea of the code above is, based on the database type, get the correct singleton from NestJS scope. This way it's easy to add a new database if you want - just add a new type and it's implementation. (and your code can handle multiple databases at the same time!)

3. I also believe you can simply pass the already injected `LoggerService` and `IOService` to the `DatabasesService` you create manually (You would need to add `IOService` as a dependency of `DatabaseServce`

```js
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
  constructor(common: CommonService, logger: LoggerService, ioService: IOService) {

    // eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
    const databaseType: DatabaseType = common.serverConfig.dbType as DatabaseType;

    if (databaseType === DatabaseType.JSON) {
      this.loadDatabase<JSONDatabase>(new JSONDatabase(logger, ioService));
    } else if (databaseType === DatabaseType.SQL) {
      this.loadDatabase<SQLDatabase>(new SQLDatabase(logger, ioService));
    } else {
      logger.error('Unknown database type.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, super helpful answer, thanks! I actually ended up going with an abstract `DatabaseService` class, then implement those as either JSON or SQL depending on a config parameter & a dynamic module, which seems similar to #1. I might actually switch to your #2 since it seems more reasonable for my codebase. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Incredible answer! Option 2 is what I ended up needing.